# Memory dump an app in android

Tags: android, memory, adb, root, ddms

I'm on a rooted device and want to take a complete memory dump of a certain app.

I've tried:

1. Some google results say to use "adb kill -10 [pid]"
   But, it is giving me "sigusr1 forcing gc (no hprof)", and no hproc is dumped.
   This could be device specific.
2. I've also tried using "Dump PROF file" button in DDMS (Eclipse),
   but it only gives me a file that is about 5 MB, this is not a
   complete memory dump and not very useful.
3. I've tried to chmod /proc/[pid]/mem, and access that file, but
   even on a rooted device, it is giving me permission denied.

Comment: Which code are you using to read /proc/[pid]/mem? Have you tried the code from [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)?

Comment: I'm running the code from Java on a rooted Android. I've tried almost all IO methods, the problem is I can't create a file handler of any sort. My last method was using RandomAccessFile.

Comment: I wrote a program to do just that, take a look at my answer [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/109068/95403)

Answer (score 0):

HPROF is a dump of heap alone, so it is obviously not *all* memory. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640182/why-cant-i-get-an-hprof-dump-from-certain-devices), Android no longer dumps heap on SIGUSR1 (signal 10) in newer versions. Some useful facts on using /proc/[pid]/mem are given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux). In short: your "permission denied" may as well be caused by trying to read the file in wrong way.

**EDIT**: to read anything, other than /proc/self/mem having debug permissions may be extra useful, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163678/ptrace-ptrace-attach-failure-linux-permissions-of-user-owned-process) for some insights.

Comment: Thanks! 
My reader process has root. 
Do you know how I can stop the target process to prevent a ESRCH error when trying to read?